# Java/Spring: Populate initial user data

Tags: java, spring

I am wondering what is the pattern for this. I am building an application where users can create their accounts. And once a user creates her account she gets some basic data set up such as amount of money, name of her cat, and other complex objects.

What is the best way to handle these default values?

One way is to hard code them in the Account bean. However, what happens if these default values ever have to change in production?

One naive way is to have the default values in the settings and then copy them into the Account bean when creating each user.

Though things get messy when these default values differ by user groups. For instance if the user is from Europe, I want to set her initial amount of money to 54 Euros. If she is from the US, I want to set it to -20 US Dollars. And if the user is from China, I want to assign 20 initial cars to her while assigning 10 buildings if the user is from Mexico.

As you can see these initial setup for each user can comprise some complex objects.

What is the best way/pattern to handle this in Java and Spring?

Comment: There's no best way for this. From my point of view, I would never hard code them. Use a properties file you can easily change or read them from persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Properties file is a good solution.  A database would be more initial cost but perhaps provide better long value.  You can account for the difference in values per user group by having grouped properties, such as

```
us.initial_value=-20
us.unit=USD
eu.initial_value=54
eu.unit=Euros
china.initial_valu=20
china.unit=cars
```

You could have the code provide a default value for the default, in case the value isn't read in from the file correctly.